# Logrotate not rotating file automatically

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have a rust application which is redirecting logs to some directory. In order to incorporate rolling policy I am using logrotate linux utility. For that I have created my application specific configuration file in /etc/logrotate.d :-

```
/var/log/application/myapp.log {
    hourly 
    rotate 5
    copytruncate
    dateext
}
```

However, log files are not getting rotated as per policy applied (hourly).

Also note that `logrotate` is present in directory `cron.daily`. Since I just wish for `logrotate` to rotate my logs hourly, I can't move it under `cron.hourly`.

Answer (score 0):

Hourly isn't an option with logrotate; the smallest granularity you have is daily. Check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for logrotate. I answered how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337271/how-to-run-a-logrotate-hourly/56449479#56449479), by the way.

Answer (score 0):

In order you to be able to rotate your logs on hourly base, you must configure logrotate on `/etc/cron.hourly/logrotate` file .
With your current setup e.g `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` the logrotate app will be invoked only one time per day, regardless how you've configured your logrotate configuration files.