# Trying to understand how to configure seperate logrotate configs

Tags: ubuntu, cron, logrotate

I apologize if I've misunderstood how this stuff works.

I have attempted to setup my own logrotate hourly config which doesn't seem to have taken affect in the cron tabs.

I'll provide below my files, and if anyone can point out the mistake I've made, i'd be very grateful.

/etc/logrotate_hourly.d/upstart

```
/var/log/upstart/*.log {
    hourly
    copytruncate
    missingok
    size 1M
    rotate 1
    compress
    notifempty
    nocreate
}
```

/etc/logrotate_hourly.d/nginx

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
    hourly
    missingok
    rotate 0
    size 200M
    compress
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
        postrotate
        [ ! -f /run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /run/nginx.pid`
        endscript
}
```

/etc/logrotate_hourly.conf

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate our custom log files hourly
hourly

# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate_hourly.d
```

/etc/cron.hourly/logrotate

```
#!/bin/sh

# Clean non existent log file entries from status file
cd /var/lib/logrotate
test -e status || touch status
head -1 status > status.clean
sed 's/"//g' status | while read logfile date
do
    [ -e "$logfile" ] && echo "\"$logfile\" $date"
done >> status.clean
mv status.clean status

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate_hourly.conf
```

Running the following works as expected:

```
sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate_hourly.conf
```

Runnin this also works:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate_hourly.conf
```

But the cron/hourly logrotate never seems to happen.
Everywhere you read people saying "you don't need to restart a service nor reboot for new logrotates to take affect".
I've found one person saying they had success with changing a config and rebooting. Is everyone wrong or was he lucky?
I'm trying to avoid needing to reboot as we build images for amazon's aws auto scaling, and thus it just spins up a snap shot.

Answer (score 0):

`Hourly` means nothing to logrotate, it is not a valid directive. [Man:](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

> Normally, logrotate is run as a daily cron job. It will not modify a
>   log multiple times in one day unless the criterion for that log is
>   based on the log's size and logrotate is being run multiple times each
>   day, or unless the -f or --force option is used.

I've explained how you can do this kind of thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337271/how-to-run-a-logrotate-hourly/56449479#56449479). Your difference is that you do not need to force the rotation with -f but you do need to rotate based on log size and only its size.